# Not able to check firebase resource with editor's role

Tags: firebase

I got the invite as editor permission for firebase but I couldn't see the storage or resource.
What is the issue?

I'm just trying to check the resources .
https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-basic
Here they say "All the Viewer role permissions, plus permissions for actions that modify state, such as changing existing resources"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already experienced this...
I believe you are going to create resource on firebase? right?
If so you need to be an owner role.
If there is already resources, you should see it. then you need to check your role again. or resigin.
Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes exactly... I will try it and let you know
Thanks